# Slow mailing using WAMP

Tags: php, email, wamp, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send mails using classic PHP scripts.
Mail() version :

```
<?php
    ini_set('SMTP', 'srv-****.fr');
    ini_set('smtp_port', '25');
    $to      = 'adrien.debono-ext@fake.fr';
    $subject = 'TestMail PHP';
    $message = 'Hello just testing please ignore';
    $headers = 'From: dsi.fake@fake.fr' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: adrien.debono@fake.fr' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
     mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo('OK');
?>
```

Swift Mailer Version

```
<?php
// Test mail with swift
require_once 'swiftmailer-master/lib/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('srv-****.fr', 25);

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test Swift')
  ->setFrom(array('fake@fake.fr'))
  ->setTo('fake@hotmail.fr')
  ->setBody(' Test, please ignore')
  ;

// Send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
echo('Test.');
?>
```

When I use a simple mail() function, my page loads 2 minutes. Then the mail takes another 2 minutes to pop in my inbox. That's waayy too long.

When I try using SwiftMailer, which timeouts after 30 seconds, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection to srv-exchange.mpm.fr:25 Timed Out' in C:\wamp\www\tests\swiftmailer-master\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 407
( ! ) Swift_TransportException: Connection to srv-*****.fr:25 Timed Out in C:\wamp\www\tests\swiftmailer-master\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 407
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  241416  {main}( )   ..\mailSwift.php:0
2   0.0520  2737536 Swift_Mailer->send( )   ..\mailSwift.php:19
3   0.0520  2737960 Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start( ) ..\Mailer.php:80
4   0.0620  2754568 Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_readGreeting( ) ..\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:119
5   0.0620  2754736 Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_getFullResponse( )  ..\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:291
6   30.0660 2804816 Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_throwException( )   ..\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:409
```

What does it mean ?
How could I solve it ?

Setup : Using a WAMP server on my local platform, which is in a society network.
I'm using the SMTP server of my society.

**EDIT AFTER TESTS TODAY:**
I called the IT guys, I think the problems comes from my WAMP configuration.
Will come back to this post once I'm done finding what's messed up with my thing.

The IT guy saw the logs :
14h50 : incoming connexion from my IP adress
-- nothing for 3min30
14H54 message delivered.

He ensured me there were no mass mail protections. My telnet works fine. I think the problem comes from WAMP.

Comment: * Mentions `mail` function. Doesn't show snippet.

Comment: Looks like your public SMTP server has set the 2-min interval to prevent mass-mailing.

Comment: @GolezTrol Added the missing snipet, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I think @mudasobwa has hit the nail in the head with his remarks about mass-mailing protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, problem solved here's how :

After investigating, I found out that the problem was coming from MY setup, because absolutely everything was fine on the SMTP server side.

So I tried changing my WAMP environment :
Switched to EasyPHP from wampserver.

Everything works fine now with EasyPHP, I hugely recomand using this development environment for WAMP/LAMP devs. http://www.easyphp.org/